# GNU make read variable from a file and present to choose on prompt

Tags: bash, unix, awk, makefile, gnu-make

I do have a config file that contains multiple lines of code like

```
locals {
  env = {
    ns-marcus = {
      name                    = "marcus"
      vpc_name                = "vpc-marcus"
      subnet1_name            = "Subnet1-Marcus"
      subnet2_name            = "Subnet2-Marcus"
      route_table1_name             = "route-table-marcus"
      igw_name                      = "igw-marcus"
    }

    ns-phil = {
      name                    = "phil"
      vpc_name                = "vpc-phil"
      subnet1_name            = "Subnet1-phil"
      subnet2_name            = "Subnet2-phil"
      route_table1_name             = "route-table-phil"
      igw_name                      = "igw-phil"
    }
```

this list continuous to grow

I configured a Makefile that statically asks for the individual user on prompt and after text input commands are executed

```
all:
@echo "WORKSPACES AVAILABLE:"
@echo "marcus"
@echo "phil"

apply: all
@read -p "Enter Workspace Name: " workspace; \
terraform workspace select $$workspace
```

the issue I am now having is that if I statically add another user3 in my config file user.tf I have to manually edit the Makefile to include another @echo line for user3

Ideally I would love to read all potential users and then prompt for the configured users in user.tf

Answer (score 0):

You can just use something like `awk` to extract the workspace names from your config file:

```
all:
    @echo "WORKSPACES AVAILABLE"
    @awk '/^user/ {print $1}' config.file

apply: all
    @read -p "Enter Workspace Name: " workspace; \
    terraform workspace select $$workspace
```

Comment: thanks, regarding awk and extraction, do you happen to know if its possible to extract only the name within this statement? like user1, paul, jack? locals {
  env = {

    user1 = {
      name                    = "user1"
      vpc_cidr                = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
    }

    paul = {
      name                    = "paul"
      vpc_cidr                = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
    }

    jack = {
      name                    = "jack"
      vpc_cidr                = ["10.2.0.0/16"]
    }

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking: the example here does extract only the name. If you'd like to update your question with different example data that might be easier, because it's not possible to format things usefully in comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
MYVAR := $(shell cat workspaces.tf | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($$i == "name") {printf "%s\\n\n",$$3}}' workspaces.tf)
all:
    @echo "WORKSPACES AVAILABLE"
    @echo $(MYVAR)
```

this did it!